# Amazon ec2-register not authorised

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to bundle, upload and register an instance-store AMI from a running instance.  When it comes to calling ec2-register I get the response :

```
Client.UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

The instance is running under the permissions granted through an IAM Role.  The policy uses the data-pipline preset:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
  {
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "s3:List*",
    "s3:Put*",
    "s3:Get*",
    "s3:DeleteObject",
    "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
    "dynamodb:Scan",
    "dynamodb:Query",
    "dynamodb:GetItem",
    "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
    "dynamodb:UpdateTable",
    "rds:DescribeDBInstances",
    "rds:DescribeDBSecurityGroups",
    "redshift:DescribeClusters",
    "redshift:DescribeClusterSecurityGroups",
    "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
    "datapipeline:PollForTask",
    "datapipeline:ReportTaskProgress",
    "datapipeline:SetTaskStatus",
    "datapipeline:PollForTask",
    "datapipeline:ReportTaskRunnerHeartbeat"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "*"
  ]}
]}
```

What do I need to add here to authorise ec2-register to run?  ..or have I misunderstood how this all works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple in the end, it's just a matter of adding the right string to the action array in the JSON policy above.  I also didn't need permissions relating to dynamodb, rds, redshift or the data pipeline so I removed them.

First I fixed it by altering the permissions to be wide enough for it to work (on services I needed, S3 and EC2):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*",
        "ec2:*",
        "cloudwatch:PutMetricData"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And then narrowed it down to the exact commands I wanted to call by replacing the * in "ec2:*" with the appropriate function I wanted to call.